# Windows upgrade failed (Error 0x8007042B-0x2000D) when upgrading to build 1607

Tags: windows-10-v1607

So, I'm currently running the RTM build of Windows 10 Enterprise x64 and I downloaded `en_windows_10_enterprise_version_1607_updated_jul_2016_x64_dvd_9054264.iso` and mounted the ISO on Windows as a virtual CD. I double clicked the `setup.exe` to begin the installation, but, upon reboot and log in, I saw an error message popping up.

```
We couldn't install Windows 10
We've set your PC back to the way it was right before you started installing Windows 10.
0x8007042B - 0x2000D
The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation
```

So, this means I have to clean install Windows 10 build 1607 if I ever wanted the upgrade? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Sometimes its a driver issue, I wonder if it is the virtual cd driver, any nvidia drivers present?

Comment: 0x8007042B = ERROR_PROCESS_ABORTED . share the setup logs from C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther

Comment: I don't even know which ones are the logs, there are 40 files, some are XML, others are BIN, I repeatedly attempted to upgrade to 1607, and even to 1511, but all attempts are in vain. I will probably delete the partition and start a truly clean install...however, this is very, very annoying.

Comment: I need the setuperr and setupact.log

Answer (score 0):

This question probably got "solved" by a clean install, but as I had a similar Problem with a PC originally migrated from windows 7 and now put into a new domain. After testeing all other tips on the internet (Deleteing folders, turning off anti-virus-software, etc.), this tip solved it:

https://superuser.com/a/1494812/81175

The problem was in deed the orphaned profiles in the registry.