# In-place Upgrade to WIndows 10 failed, 0x8007042B - 0x3000D

Tags: windows-10, upgrade

We had this issue when doing an in-place upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (1903) on certain machines while many others went through the process w/o any issue.

> We couldn't install Windows 10
>
> We've set your PC back to the way it was right before you started
>   installing Windows 10.
>
> 0x8007042B - 0x3000D
>
> The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation

C:\Windows\setuperr.log

> 2019-10-18 14:10:28, Error      [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost:
>   CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext:
>   LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Windows-RasServer-MigPlugin\RasMigPlugin.dll,
>   LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7f.[gle=0x0000007f]
>   2019-10-18 14:10:28, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost:
>   CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc:
>   LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed
>   hr=0x8007007f.[gle=0x0000007f] 2019-10-18 14:20:29, Error
>   [0x08085f] MIG    MigHost:
>   CMigPluginSurrogate::LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext:
>   LoadLibraryExW(C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests\Microsoft-Windows-RasServer-MigPlugin\RasMigPlugin.dll,
>   LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) failed gle=0x7f.[gle=0x0000007f]
>   2019-10-18 14:20:29, Error      [0x080863] MIG    MigHost:
>   CMigPluginSurrogate::COMGenericThreadingHostThreadProc:
>   LoadAndRegisterServerInThreadContext() failed
>   hr=0x8007007f.[gle=0x0000007f]

The affected machines would finish all the installation process but stopped when loading updates around 40% t0 65% and would reboot and revert to Windows 7.

Disabling AV, running `sfc/scannow`, and check the installation file integrity didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3398b673-f981-43c2-ad9d-da7731bed485/the-installation-failed-in-the-firstboot-phase-with-an-error-during-migratedata-operation?forum=win10itprogeneral) gave me an idea as I realized all affected machines are migrated from another domain while carrying over previous user profiles.

Here is what to do if you have a similar issue,

1. Under
   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, check if you can find multiple user profiles with the same user Ids (but different SID).
2. Backup registry, won't hurt to do a full and a partial for this particular path.
3. Get SID of the current users or all users you want to preserve by running `whoami /user` in their session.
4. Removed all but user profiles with the SIDs you just gathered.
5. Reboot the machine to verify user profile association, so users can still log in and access their old files.
6. Start upgrade.