# Windows update from 1803 fails with 0x8007042B - 0x2000D SAFE_OS phase during MIGRATE_DATA operation

Tags: windows-10

I am updating a Windows 10 PC from 1803 (to the latest OS which is 1909) and it's failing with this error:

`0x8007042B - 0x2000D The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation`

It fails the same way each time, pretty much down to the time intervals between the various errors in the setup log.

So far I've tried the following:

- uninstall third party anti virus
- run various dsim and sfc commands, none of which reported any errors / corruptions
- performed a clean boot using msconfig (disable all non microsoft services and startup apps)

None of which makes any difference.

The setupdiag tool reports the following:

```
Matching Profile found: FindFatalPluginFailure - E48E3F1C-26F6-4AFB-859B-BF637DA49636
SetupDiag version: 1.6.0.0
System Information:
    Machine Name = JOHN-HP
    Manufacturer = HP
    Model = HP Pavilion Desktop 590-p0xxx
    HostOSArchitecture = 2057
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 20181101000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = F.20
    BiosVersion = F.20
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.17134
    HostOSBuildString = 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.18362.590 (19h1_release_svc_prod1.191209-1753)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Core
    RegisteredAV = Windows Defender
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 18/01/2020 9:11:54 PM
    UpgradeEndTime = 18/01/2020 9:36:18 PM
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 00:24:24
    CV = 
    ReportId = 


Error: SetupDiag reports fatal migration plug-in failure.
Last Phase: Safe OS 
Last Operation: Offline portion of first and oobe boot apply operations

Plug-in Name = %windir%\system32\migration\SxsMigPlugin.dll
Migration Operation = IPostApply->PostApply
Plug-in Error: 0x00000002

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Safe OS
    Phase Started: 18/01/2020 9:29:09 PM
    Phase Ended: 1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: Offline portion of first and oobe boot apply operations
    Operation Started: 18/01/2020 9:34:33 PM
    Operation Ended: 1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

So not super interesting there.

The setuperr log file from `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther` has the following:

```
2020-01-18 21:12:19, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #10# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = a38 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup'), vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:12:19, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #9# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:31]'\Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\Setup\', vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1253): Result = 0xC1800104[gle=0x00000002]
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::CheckUserInterruptEx(3060): Result = 0x800704D3
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::CheckUserInterrupt(3112): Result = 0x800704D3
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(794): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(392): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(284): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-01-18 21:12:29, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(420): Result = 0x800705BB
2020-01-18 21:13:16, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #38# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = ba8 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup'), vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:13:16, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #37# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:31]'\Registry\Machine\SYSTEM\Setup\', vn = [l:7 ml:8]'Compact', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:13:18, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #70# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysQueryValueKey(flags = 0, key = bf4 ('\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts'), vn = [l:21 ml:22]'Arial Nova (TrueType)', kvic = 2, kvi = 2, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:13:18, Error                 CSI    00000004 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #69# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CKey::QueryValue(flags = 0, kn = [l:69]'\Registry\Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts\', vn = [l:21 ml:22]'Arial Nova (TrueType)', ic = KeyValuePartialInformation, info = {l:0 b:}, disp = 0)[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:18:11, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to set WU internal configuration property for targeted scans. hr = 0x80070057
2020-01-18 21:18:45, Error                 CONX   0xd0000034 Failed to add user mode driver [%SystemRoot%\system32\DRIVERS\UMDF\uicciso.dll]

2020-01-18 21:24:50, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2020-01-18 21:25:41, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2020-01-18 21:27:18, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2020-01-18 21:27:18, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2020-01-18 21:28:23, Error                 MOUPG  Finalize: Error obtaining Update and Shutdown Key: [0x80070002][gle=0x000000b7]
2020-01-18 21:28:29, Error                 SP     BFSVC: Error copying boot debugging files from C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\system32 to \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume3\EFI\Microsoft\Boot (kd_*_*.dll). Last Error = 0x6[gle=0x00000006]
2020-01-18 21:28:29, Error                 SP     BFSVC: Error copying boot debugging files from C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\system32 to \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolume3\EFI\Microsoft\Boot (kdstub.dll). Last Error = 0x6[gle=0x00000006]
2020-01-18 21:34:43, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: offline key (new) = '$OFFLINE_RW_026508B3$SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\Bridge'
2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: query bridge presence key failed 0x139f, bridge present = 0
2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(607)\shmig.dll!00007FFBED8871BA: (caller: 00007FFBED885115) ReturnHr(1) tid(588) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Migrated key for Path $OFFLINE_RW_026508B3$SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema.Migrated for 32-bit hive not found ] 

2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(607)\shmig.dll!00007FFBED8871BA: (caller: 00007FFBED885148) ReturnHr(2) tid(588) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Migrated key for Path $OFFLINE_RW_026508B3$SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema.Migrated for 64-bit hive not found ] 

2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error      [0x08038d] MIG    Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll", CLSID={43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x80070002
2020-01-18 21:35:54, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x00000002 while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll,{43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6},Apartment. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    0000002c@2020/1/18:21:35:56.324 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\ntsystem.cpp(2926): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    0000002d (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #193461# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = 0, handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (FILE_GENERIC_READ), oa = @0xd0d47fbd88->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[109]'\??\D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Store\MachineSpecific\File\srcworkingalias\agentmgr\CCSIAgent\005A53BA\SxsAsm10\ATL80.dll'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0xd0d47fbe00, as = (null), fa = (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL), sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|F[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    ILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd = FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    0000002e (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #193460# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CSystemIsolationLayer_IRtlSystemIsolationLayerTearoff::TransferFileEx(flags = (OpenForBackupIntent), op = 'Copy', odir = NULL, oname = [l:109]'\??\D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Store\MachineSpecific\File\srcworkingalias\agentmgr\CCSIAgent\005A53BA\SxsAsm10\ATL80.dll', ndir = @0x1da47514280, nname = [l:42 ml:63]'f43e6c4447ced501a600000094048805_atl80.dll', disp = Unmapped disposition: 0)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    0000002f@2020/1/18:21:35:56.324 (F) onecore\base\wcp\sil\ntsystem.cpp(2926): Error STATUS_DELETE_PENDING originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    00000030 (F) STATUS_DELETE_PENDING #193487# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = (AllowSharingViolation), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (DELETE|SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES), oa = @0xd0d47fbf50->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[129]'\??\D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\InFlight\f43e6c4447ced501a300000094048805\f43e6c4447ced501a400000094048805_manifest'; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0[gle=0xd0000056]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    xd0d47fc190, as = (null), fa = (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL), sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd = FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000056]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    00000031 (F) STATUS_DELETE_PENDING #193483# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory::Internal_DeleteRecursively(...)[gle=0xd0000056]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 CSI    00000032 (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) #193215# from Windows::COM::CComponentStore::InternalTransact(...)[gle=0x80070002]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {d2caca93-9eef-4c24-9790-61cdefd255d4}: Install assembly D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Store\MachineSpecific\File\srcworkingalias\agentmgr\CCSIAgent\005A53BA\ failed with 0x80070002 during Offline; this is a fatal condition
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error      [0x080390] MIG    Failure while calling IPostApply->PostApply for Plugin={ServerPath="%windir%\system32\migration\SxsMigPlugin.dll", CLSID={d2caca93-9eef-4c24-9790-61cdefd255d4}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x80070002
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 MIG    Error 0x00000002 while executing critical action Action,CMXEPlugin,D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Work\MachineSpecific\Working\agentmgr\CCSIAgent,%windir%\system32\migration\SxsMigPlugin.dll,{d2caca93-9eef-4c24-9790-61cdefd255d4},Apartment. Migration will abort[gle=0x000000cb]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                        Apply failed. Last error: 0x00000000
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 SP     pSPExecuteApply: Apply operation failed. Error: 0x0000002C
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 SP     Apply (first boot apply, offline phase): Migration phase failed. Result: 44[gle=0x00000002]
2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Offline portion of first and oobe boot apply operations. Error: 0x8007042B[gle=0x000000b7]
2020-01-18 21:36:18, Error                 SP     Cannot revert execution of operation 60 (Cleanup source WIM file(s)). Execution queue is now compromised.[gle=0x00000012]
2020-01-18 21:36:18, Error                 SP     Operation execution failed: 13. hr = 0x8007042B[gle=0x00000012]
2020-01-18 21:36:18, Error                 SP     ExecuteOperations: Failed execution phase Safe OS. Error: 0x8007042B[gle=0x00000012]
2020-01-18 21:36:18, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatformPrivate::Execute: Execution of operations queue failed, abandoning. Error: 0x8007042B[gle=0x00000012]
```

I think the interesting errors are timestamped at `2020-01-18 21:35:56` where it complains about a file not being found.

What's odd here is that the path to the plugin that appears to be failing:

`2020-01-18 21:35:56, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {d2caca93-9eef-4c24-9790-61cdefd255d4}: Install assembly D:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Store\MachineSpecific\File\srcworkingalias\agentmgr\CCSIAgent\005A53BA\`

is referring to D:\ drive, however this PC has no D:\ drive..\

Any ideas other than re-install windows?

This is a relatives PC and has some applications installed on it that the vendor wont provide a license key for (they have a cloud based subscription model now :( )

I've looked for details of the plugin `CCSIAgent` but the web is just full of error logs with a similar sort of update error.

**EDIT**

I've since tried the DSIM and SFC commands again:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1246]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17134.1

Image Version: 10.0.17134.1246

[===========================98.0%========================  ]
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17134.1

Image Version: 10.0.17134.1246

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

===RESTART===

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1246]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I then re-ran the update process from my ISO flash drive. It crashed at the same point, error logs are the same as before...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-place Upgrade to WIndows 10 failed, 0x8007042B - 0x3000D](https://superuser.com/questions/1494811/in-place-upgrade-to-windows-10-failed-0x8007042b-0x3000d)

Comment: @stringy05 - I am not suggesting you remove any application

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1175497/windows-10-update-0xc1900101-0x3000d-first-boot-and-migrate-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1524136/windows-10-update-fails-with-0x8007001f

Comment: This wasn't it. The profiles were in the normal spot, on the c: drive

Comment: Have you tried downloading a Windows 10 version 1809 and try upgrading to that?  When you performed this upgrade that fails, what other devices did you have connected, be as specific as possible?  1803 had issues going to 1809 when there were additional volumes.  This was fixed eventually fixed in a cumulative patch.