# Windows 10 update fails with 0x8007001F

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to perform an in-place update of Windows 10 from 1803 to 1909.

The update downloads successfully. It starts the update, restarts several times and at some point says the update has failed and it is restoring the previous version. The computer restarts again and works fine.

When I check the update history, I can see that the update has failed with the error code 0x8007001F.

I've tried running Windows Update Troubleshooter and applied all recommended fixes: Cleaned update cache, downloaded updates again, reconstructed update database etc. It kept failing each time.

Contacted MS support and they instructed me to download the ISO image of 1909 and do the update from the image. Failed once agai then they recommended me to backup my files and perform a clean install, which is not an option.

I even downloaded ISO images of Windows 10 version 1809, 1903 and 1909 to perform each upgrade separately and all failed. When upgrading with an ISO image I could get an additional error message that says:

> 0x80070004 - 0x3000D The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase
>   with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation

Anyone with an idea of how to perform an in-place upgrade?

Comment: 0x8007001F decodes to 31. `net helpmsg 31` returns `A device attached to the system is not functioning.`. 0x80070004 decodes to 4 `net helpmsg 4` returns `The system cannot open the file.` See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/decoding-errors.html for decoding errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to update Windows.

Due to company policy on our computers, the *Default* and *Public* user profiles are in the *Users* folder on drive C: and actual user profiles are also in *Users* folder but are on another drive.

**It turns out Windows 10 update does not like it when your user profile is on another drive and fails while migrating your user profile to the new version**.

I've moved my profile to drive C (moved the files and updated some registry keys, there are many articles about this online) then the update from 1803 to 1909 was completed without a hickup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the built-in administrator account which was disabled. I enabled it (just that, nothing else) and the update was installed smoothly.